# Black body balloon in vacuum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, thermal-radiation, ideal-gas

**The problem statement, all variables and given/known data**

There is a perfectly spherical balloon with surface painted black. It is placed in a perfect vacuum. It is gently inflated with an ideal mono-atomic gas at Kelvin temperature $T_i$, slowly enough so that it reaches thermal equilibrium with the gas, and then it is sealed off. It has radius $r_i$ at this time and contains N atoms. The vacuum is large, so radiation from its walls can be ignored.

a) Show that $\frac{T}{T_i}= \left(\frac{r}{r_i}\right)^3$ if the pressure inside the balloon is independent of its radius.

b) How much energy does the balloon radiate per second when it is at radius $r$? Express your answer in terms of $r$ and constants.

c) What is the rate of change of the internal energy of the gas? Express you answer in terms of $r$, $r˙$, and constants.

**Relevant equations:**

$$PV = nRT$$

$$J * A = σT^4 (4\pi r^2)$$

**The attempt at a solution:**

I already showed a), so I don't need help with that.
In part b), I wrote pretty much 
$J * A = σT^4 (4\pi r^2)$
but I am unsure how to get a speed of radiation. 
I also have no idea how to do part c), so any help on parts b) or c) is welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what J*A is, so i'm not exactly sure which form of Stefan's law you're using. I think that if you use the following form, you should be fine: 
$$\frac{\mathrm dQ_b}{\mathrm dt}=A\sigma T^4$$ Here, $\mathrm Q_b$ is the radiant energy emitted by a perfectly black body in a small time $\mathrm dt$, so $\frac{\mathrm dQ_b}{\mathrm dt}$ is the rate of emission of energy. $A$ is the surface area of balloon.

I think that b and c become pretty easy once you use this formula. Fortunately, we have a vacuum, so we don't have to consider energy absorbed or work done against vacuum.

Comment: Just out of interest, Is $J$ some sort of heat-current-density? It looks like emissive power to me..

Comment: To clarify, Q is the energy? Not the heat?
Then what I wrote for part b is basically correct?
Also for part c, the internal energy shouldn't be the same as the emitted energy right?

Comment: @EricMercer: By first law of thermodynamics, $Q=U+w$. $Q$ is heat, $U$ is internal energy. $w$ is work, but it is zero here because its a vacuum. So here, `heat lost`=`decrease in internal energy`. So they're the same here.

Comment: I guess what you did for b is correct. $dQ/dt$ is the amount of energy radiated per second. For c, since $Q=U$, their corresponding rates are the same as well (there may be a $\pm$, though).

Comment: If it helps, the $Q$ used in the first law of thermoD is $-Q_b$ here (since I took energy *emitted*)

Comment: Oh I see, vacuum makes the work 0. 
So basically since everything else is held constant, the only thing affecting both the energy radiated and internal energy is the surface area, which is determined by the radius.

Comment: But what about the law that 
dU = TdS - PdV?
Pressure is basically held constant for the sake of the problem, volume changes based on radius?

Comment: @EricMercer: Pressure is 0. It's *external* pressure we're talking about (we don't care about the work done by balloon on system, we care about the _energy lost when it expands *against* external pressure_ ). Anyways, $dU=TdS-PdV$ won't get you much. You need to calculate entropy. If you try, you basically get $dQ=TdS; \: dU=dQ-dw$. Back to the FLTD.

Comment: So for part c), I am supposed to get:
(9*N*k*T_i*r^2*r')/(2r_i^3) and I am unsure how to get to that.

Comment: Hmmm.. It looks like you're supposed to use $dU=nC_VdT$. Which means that there is some energy being lost in keeping the internal pressure constant. For a monoatomic gas, $C_v=\frac{3R}{2}$

Comment: Yean, $nC_VdT seems to give the answer.

Comment: Huh...no where does the problem say that energy is being lost for that, which makes sense, I just thought they might have included it.
That's irritating. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @EricMercer: It need not be stated, you sort of have to figure that out.. Yeah, it gets annoying when problems specify additional constraints like "pressure constant" which lead to energy loss since something has to work to keep it constant.

Comment: Yeah I guess I should have worked that out from the fact that the pressure is kept constant. Once again, thanks for everything!